# Создание Логера для конкретный классов

Tags: c#, nlog

Для логирования используется NLog. Т.к. логи необходимы в разных проектах решения, то появилась идея лоигрования в одном месте (чтобы не добавлять NLog в каждый проект и агрегировать всю работу с NLog в одном конкретном месте). Для этого сделал следующее:

```
public static Dictionary<Type, Logger> logger_map = new Dictionary<Type, Logger>();

public static LoggingManager CreateLogger(Type source_class)
{
    if (!logger_map.Keys.Contains(source_class))
    {
        logger_map.Add(source_class, LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(source_class));
    }

    return new LoggingManager();
}
```

В LoggingManager логирование делается так:

```
//получили логер для конкретного класса
var logger = CoreHelper.logger_map[<class_type>];
logger.Log(...);
```

Проблема в том, что для каждого логера не указывается не переданный класс(source_class), а тот, из которого вызывается CreateLogger. Можно ли решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `чтобы не добавлять NLog в каждый проект` - советую вам познать дзен с IoC контейнерами, которые без проблем привяжут вам любую реализацию на простой интерфейс, который вы без проблем можете использовать где угодно и как угодно.

Comment: Имеет ли смысл использовать IoC-контейнеры для такой небольшой задачи? За замечание спасибо, но  вопрос был в другом: Почему не работает ```LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(source_class)``` =)

Comment: А я вам и не отвечаю, это лишь комментарий, напутствие, совет. `для такой небольшой задачи?` - я уверен, что у вас там есть что засунуть в контейнер помимо логгера. Сейчас вы делаете статичный класс, а статика в C# зло, уж лучше синглтон.

Comment: Статичный класс только с CreateLogger, это Helper) Сам же LoggingManager без статики

Comment: Ок, а почему вы тип передаете через параметры, а не через положенный для этого генерик? Наверно должно быть `LoggingManager CreateLogger<T>(){... LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger<T>(); }`?

Comment: Да, действительно, это удобнее. Назовем это...мм...досадной опечаткой =)

Comment: Все еще Актуально